# Constraints and localization in ios7

Tags: ios

i'm working on app that will support arabic and english

arabic is RTL language

english is LTR language

so when i was working on design i put constraints to all labels trailing space and leading space so when i change ios device language the labels positioned correctly according to the selected language

what i mean is if i have two labels in the same line as the following

label 1    label 2

in case of english

label 1    label 2

label 1 position in the left and label 2 is to right of it

in case of arabic

label 2    label 1
label 2 in the left and label 1 to right of it

that is what i want and it is what is happening now

now i want to set language from my application

i put this code in main.m

```
NSArray *lang=  [defaults objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
        [defaults setObject:@[lang[0]] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
        [defaults synchronize];
```

and in my button action which change language this code

```
-(IBAction)changeLang:(id)sender{

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

   NSArray *lang=  [defaults objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"];

    if ([lang[0] isEqualToString:@"ar"]) {

        [defaults setObject:@[@"en"] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];

    }else{

        [defaults setObject:@[@"ar"] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];

    }



     [defaults synchronize];

    exit(0);



}
```

when i open my application again it listen to the language change and all labels and strings are localized

without exit(0) nothing happens my application language still the same

what i want to do

my application reload all views without exit(0); after language change or after exit(0) open my application again if it possible

Comment: `exit(0)` will get your app rejected by Apple if you need to publish this on app store.

Comment: i will publish app on store i know that it is illegal i need your suggestion to solve my problem

Comment: Hi I am having the same issue here... did you, by chance, find any solution for this?

Comment: i am sorry i don't get the solution yet :(